# Use JS function in place of repeating code

Tags: javascript, function

I know this should be easy.. but im still learning JS :)

this code works fine, but currently I will have to repeat this about 20 times, just changing the L50C object, and the xp_50...

```
let L50C = document.getElementById('lvl50');
chrome.storage.sync.get('L50color', function(data) {L50C.setAttribute('value', data.L50color);
});
let L60C = document.getElementById('xp_60');
chrome.storage.sync.get('L60color', function(data) {L60C.setAttribute('value', data.L60color);
});

L40C.onchange = function(element) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.insertCSS(
          tabs[0].id,
          {code: ".xp_40 {border: 1px solid " + element.target.value + " !important;} .xp_40 .icon {color: " + element.target.value + " !important;}"});
    });
  };
L50C.onchange = function(element) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.insertCSS(
          tabs[0].id,
          {code: ".xp_50 {border: 1px solid " + element.target.value + " !important;} .xp_50 .icon {color: " + element.target.value + " !important;}"});
    });
  };
```

(im using #60 to test)
  so.. if I change the id="xp_60" like this...

```
<div class="lvl_inp_cont">Level 60: <input id="xp_60" type="text" class="lvl_input" maxlength="7"></div>
```

can i call a function to repeat... like this:

```
L60C.onchange = swap(element);

function swap(element) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.insertCSS(
          tabs[0].id,
          {code: "." + element.id + " {border: 1px solid " + element.target.value + " !important;} ." + element.id + " .icon {color: " + element.target.value + " !important;}"});
    });
  };
```

see so instead of all that code, i can just set it to one re-usable code? 
I feel like the swap function looks right (if not i can fix it) - its just how do I "call" or set the onchange to that function?

Thanks!!

EDIT:
am i close?

```
const obj = {L40C, L50C, L60C, L70C};

for(let num = 40; num < 150; num+=10) {
    let obj['L' + num + 'C'] = document.getElementById('xp_' + num);
}
```

Comment: added another (L40C), and showed where I am setting the L40C.. - yes the xp_ will be the naming element because it would match what I am altering in the CSS so I could, as show, grab the ID of xp_XX and use it along with the value (in the textbox) - or is there also a more efficient way to fo the let L40C = doc...

Comment: `L60C.onchange = swap(element);` is calling the method right away as you may have seen. When you set an event handler the first argument for the handler (which you have as `element` in both examples is actually the `event`. `event.target` has the reference to the element that triggered the event. So setting `L60C.onchange = swap;` is closer to what you want, but you'll still have to make some changes.

Comment: So `L50C` refers to `#lvl50` and `L60C` refers to `#xp_60`, and not, for example, to `#lvl60`? That'll make DRY code harder

Comment: Also, `.xp_40` refers to a *class name* of `xp_40` (in the upper code), but in the bottom you're concatenating with `"." + element.id`, which is an `id`, not a `className`? (also `element` in your lower code actually refers to the *event*, not the *element*, see answer)

Comment: yep the xp_60 was just a test (I am going to change all if it works), and.. yeah I caught that element.id should be element.target.id  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the numbers, like the `40` in `L40C.onchange` are what change each time, so I'd create an array of all such numbers, then iterate over them and assign the appropriate `chrome.tabs.query`. But you'll need an object or array of the `LC40`, `LC50`s, rather than tens of separate variable names - for example:

```
const obj = { L40C, L50C, ... };
```

Then, you can use variables for property access, and instead of your `L40C.onchange` and `L50C.onchange`, you could do:

```
['40', '50'].forEach((num) => {
  const className = 'xp_' + num;
  obj['L' + num + 'C'].onchange = ({ target }) => {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
      chrome.tabs.insertCSS(
        tabs[0].id,
        {code: "." + className + ' {border: 1px solid " + target.value + " !important;} .' + className + ' .icon {color: ' + target.value + ' !important;}'}
       );
    });
  };
});
```

It's important to note that the parameter to the `onchange` handler is an *event*, not an *element*. `event.target` refers to the element that triggered the event.

Comment: I like you 2nd example (for ease of use..) i will give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

So you should just need to set:

```
function swap(element) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.insertCSS(
          tabs[0].id,
          {code: "." + element.id + " {border: 1px solid " + element.target.value + " !important;} ." + element.id + " .icon {color: " + element.target.value + " !important;}"});
    });
  };

L40C.onchange = swap;
L50C.onchange = swap;
```

Or you could loop over an array of objects and set it there:

```
var arr = [L40C, L50C];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  arr[i].onchange = swap;
}
```

Comment: if my attempt at the array doesnt work, your 1st example did! thank you!

Comment: oo what about something like this?  for (i=40; i < 160; i+=10) {
 L+i+C.onchange=swap;
}

Comment: You could use something like this: for(var i = 0; i < 160; i+=10){document.getElementById("L" + i +  "C").onchange = swap;}